# С++. Решение квадратного уравнения

Tags: c++, математика, инспекция-кода

Написал программу для вычисления корней квадратного уравнения.
Сам, можно сказать, новичок в программировании, и хотелось бы узнать мнение тех кто имеет опыт в программировании.
Насколько код ниже соответствует современным требованиям? Какие основные ошибки и замечания можно сделать к нему?
Огромное спасибо всем! Приму и учту любую критику.

```
#include <C:\Users\leavemealone\Desktop\cpp_1\source\here_code\std_lib_facilities.h>

using namespace std;

double first_koef = 0, sec_koef = 0, third_koef = 0;// коэфициенты квадратного уравнения
double discriminant = 0;
double result_1 = 0, result_2 = 0;
double func_discr(double a, double b, double c); // прототип функции

int main() {
    cout << "Write x1, x2, x3 please" << endl;
    try {//начало try
        if(cin >> first_koef){}//если всё ОК - ничего не делаем
        else {
            throw 1; // выбрасываем исключение      
        }
        if(cin >> sec_koef){}//аналогично
        else {
            throw 1; 
        }
        if(cin >> third_koef){}//аналогично
        else {
            throw 1; 
        }
        func_discr(first_koef, sec_koef, third_koef); // функция подсчёта дискриминанта
        result_1 = (-sec_koef + sqrt(discriminant)) / 2*first_koef;//первый корень уравнения
        result_2 = (-sec_koef - sqrt(discriminant)) / 2*first_koef;//второй корень уравнения

        if(result_1 == result_2) {//если результаты одинаковые - выводим один
            cout << "X = " << result_1 << endl;
            _getch();
        }else{//если нет, оба результаты
        cout << "X1 = " << result_1 << "\tX2 = " << result_2 << endl;
        _getch();
        }
    return 0;   
}//end of try
catch(int i) {
    cout << "ERROR in koef! Press any key to exit" << endl;
        _getch();
        return 1;
}//end of catch
}//end of main

//Вычисление дискриминанта.
double func_discr(double a, double b, double c) {
    try {
        discriminant = b*b - 4*a*c;
        if(discriminant < 0) {
            throw 2;
        }else {         
            return discriminant;
        }
    }
    catch(int i) {
    cout << "CRITICAL ERROR! D < 0!" << endl;
    _getch();
    }

}
```

Comment: @АлексейУколов, ознакомься: [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review)

Comment: @АлексейУколов, это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Возможно, стоит заглянуть в [другую тему про квадратное уравнение](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/493559/178988).

Comment: @Harry, считаю неправильным переформатировать код в вопросах с меткой [tag:инспекция-кода].

Comment: Вдогонку - по-хорошему, это большая сложная задача, как ни странно - если рассматривать достижение максимальной *точности* вычислений...

Comment: @Qwertiy По здравому размышлению - да, согласен. Как там отмотать?...

Comment: @Harry, скопипастить код из версии автора? Откат вроде не в тему, т. к. потеряются другие правки текста.

Comment: @Qwertiy Вроде вернул. Приношу всем извинения за поспешное внесение правки... :(

Comment: просто замечание - ""Write x1, x2, x3 please" - у квадратного уравнения есть имена для коэффициентов - a,b,c. А x1, x2, x3 - это корни уравнения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чуток подправленый вариант, правда в логику не вникал, что там должно получиться.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double discr(double a, double b, double c) {
    double d = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (d < 0)
        throw std::runtime_error("D < 0!");
    return d;
}

int main() try {
    cout << "Enter a, b, c" << endl;
    cin.exceptions(istream::failbit | istream::badbit);
    double a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;

    double d = discr(a, b, c);
    double x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    double x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);

    if (x1 != x2)
        cout << "X1 = " << x1 << "\tX2 = " << x2 << endl;
    else
        cout << "X = " << x1 << endl;

    return 0;
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    cout << e.what() << endl;
    return 1;
}
```

- выброшен ваш странный `include` за ненадобностью
- глобальные переменные заменены на локальные по месту использования
- исключения сразу включаются для `std::cin`, чтобы не обрабатывать отдельно каждый случай (раз вы уж решили использовать исключения)
- исключения обрабатываются в одном месте
- добавлены скобки (не знаю почему, просто верю Harry)
- переименованы переменные
- ???????
- что-то ещё по мелочи

Если предполагается переиспользование в дальнейшем, код решателя можно вынести в отдельную функцию:

```
std::pair <double, double> solver(double k1, double k2, double k3) {
    double d = discr(k1, k2, k3);
    double x1 = (-k2 + sqrt(d)) / (2 * k1);
    double x2 = (-k2 - sqrt(d)) / (2 * k1);
    return std::make_pair(x1, x2);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно.
Чтобы использовать функцию непосредственно в main(), нужно всегда писать её выше блока main?
По другому никак?

Comment: @ТарасСус не обязательно, достаточно её только объявить раньше чем `main`, как у вас и было сделано. Идея в том, что в месте где вызывается функция `discr` компилятор уже должен знать как её вызвать. Для этого ему нужно знать какие аргументы она принимает, и какой результат возвращает. Но не обязательно знать как работает. Т.е. хватает только декларации. Но в коротких программах (как здесь), когда таких ф-ий несколько, проще написать их сразу, чтобы не дублировать. Это только вопрос стиля.

Answer (score 4):

**Зачем такие страсти с препроцессором**

Какой-то страшный инклуд сверху. Выбросить, заменить стандартными.

**Пространство имен замусорено. Сохранить (Y/N/MayBe)?**

`using namespace` в общем случае засоряет глобальное пространство имен. Допускаются частные варианты - `using std::cout`, как пример.

**Долой глобальные сущности, пока они ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО не востребованы**

Глобальные переменные в данном случае бессмысленны. В общем случае, глобальные сущности вредны для дизайна и от них необходимо избавляться.

**Выдача строк строго по талонам после дождичка в четверг у свистящего рака**

Определение нескольких переменных на одной строке не соответствует моему личному code-style. Переменная на строке должна быть ровно одна и к ней должен быть комментарий.

**Исключительно глупые исключения**

Исключение можно выбрасывать более осмысленное - либо унаследованное от `std::logic_error`, либо просто завести свой тип.

**Чертовы египетские скобки**

```
 if(cin >> first_koef){}//если всё ОК - ничего не делаем
        else {
            throw 1; // выбрасываем исключение      
        }
```

Я понимаю, Кернигану и Ритчи строки выдавали по талонам. Но зачем себя мучать?

```
if(cin >> first_koef)
{
}   //если всё ОК - ничего не делаем
else 
{
   throw 1; // выбрасываем исключение      
}
```

Блоки кода визуально отделены и читабельность лучше. Не надо выискивать скобки по всему тексту.

**Функция общается с программой через глобальную переменную**

Мастдай однозначно. В реальном проекте с автора будет спущена шкура во время code-review. Спущена с особым цинизмом.

## ИТОГИ

Самое страшное тут - глобальные переменные и самоуправство с препроцессором. Ревью у меня вы не прошли.

Comment: А про слона? :) Главное, что считает она неверно - ну, например, для частного случая линейного уравнения (`first_koef == 0`) корни всегда нули :)

Comment: Ревью и так не пройдено из-за глобальных переменных. Нет смысла выверять еще и логику.

Comment: _"Нет смысла выверять еще и логику."_ - не согласен. Логика важнее.

Answer (score 4):

Как минимум, нельзя так злоупотреблять исключениями.

Не нужен полный путь в `#include`.

Тут

```
(-sec_koef + sqrt(discriminant)) / 2*first_koef;
```

Нужны скобки

```
(-sec_koef + sqrt(discriminant)) / (2*first_koef);
```

Вычислять дискриминант через глобальную переменную не нужно. Вообще, чем меньше глобальных переменных - тем лучше. Вычисление дискриминанта вообще не такое сложное, чтобы его в отдельную функцию выносить. Но если выносить - то достаточно

```
double discr(double a, double b, double c)
{
    return b*b - 4*a*c;
}
```

и уж точно не надо обрабатывать в ней событие, что дискриминант меньше нуля (тем более что при этом у вас функция возвращает непойми что)...

Вот, для начала...

Comment: а почему там скобки ненужны? вроде делить на 2а и  делить на 2 умножить на а - эот разные вещи

Comment: @Grundy Где вы прочли слово **НЕ**? Я написал - **нужны** скобки.

Comment: Вот теперь не знаю :-D Похоже как-то не так читал :)